# no puedo cerrar un pop-up

Tags: javascript, html5

El siguiente código pertenece a un pop-up que estoy intentando cerrar con javascript pero no me funciona y tampoco me da ningún error.

```
<div id="popup-box-outer">
    <div id="popup-box">
    <h1><img src="<?=$path?>images/lingerie/logo-confirm.png" style="width: 135px; height: 130px; margin-left: 310px;"></h1>
    <p style="color: #fff;">Clinica Doctor Amor contiene material sexualmente explícito que puede ser ofensivo para algunos espectadores. Por favor, lea y acepte los términos y condiciones.</p>
     <p style="color: #fff;">
    Este sitio web provee acceso a material, información y comentarios que pueden ser considerados de carácter exclusivamente adulto y puede ser considerado ofensivo según sus principios sociales, morales y/o religiosos.</p>
 <p style="color: #fff;">
 Absténgase de entrar a este sitio si usted fácilmente puede ofenderse o si los estándares en su comunidad no permiten la visualización de algún material erótico adulto. Si usted no ha adquirido la mayoría de edad (mayor de 18 años) opte por SALIR de esta página inmediatamente. </p>
    <p style="color: #fff;">
        Al entrar a este sitio web y visualizar su contenido, usted está explícitamente afirmando que:
    </p>

<div class="divider-sm"> </div>
  <p>

    <a class="btn" onclick="top.close();" style="margin-left: 200px; font-weight: bold;"><?= texto('estoy de acuerdo') ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <a href="#" class="btn" onclick="history.go(-1);" style="font-weight: bold;"><?= texto('no estoy de acuerdo') ?></a>

  <p>


</div>
</div>
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa que evita cerrar este pop-up usando el código javascript que adjunto en esta pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

Una ventana sólo puede cerrarse con Javascript si ha sido abierta previamente con Javascript.

Lo que pides con `top` es una referencia a la ventana padre, que no puede cerrarse a sí misma. Prueba con `window.close();` simplemente.

O mejor aún, cambia la visibilidad de `div class="divider-sm"`: `display:block` cuando quieras mostrarlo, `display:none` cuando quieras ocultarlo. Jugando un poco con CSS tendrás un popup con el aspecto que desees.

Answer (score 0):

simplemente elimina los contenedores del texto que esta dentro del anchor, estan provocando error y no permite se ejecute `history.go(-1`) :

```
<?= texto('no estoy de acuerdo') ?>
```

Sería únicammente:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" onclick="history.go(-1);" style="font-weight: bold;">no estoy de acuerdo</a>
```